# Knockout not updating on input value changed with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datepicker

So I have to collect a date and time from the user. I want to be able to set both from a single picker.  I found this nice one by curious solutions [here](http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/).  Our site uses jQuery, jQuery mobile, and Knockout.  When I use the datepicker to select the date my knockout binded variable is not updating, even though the value of the input box has changed.  If I use jQuery to get the value it shows up just fine.

So my question: *Can someone help me figure out how to get my knockout binding to update?*

I've already tried setting the valueUpdate to `input`, and `afterkeydown` with no luck.

Here is a link to a fiddle I made that demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueEddie/eg6zM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plugin, when the value of the element is set it needs to trigger the `change` event.

Something like:

```
_setValueOfElement: function(sElemValue)
{
    var dtPickerObj = this;

    var $oElem = $(dtPickerObj.dataObject.oInputElement);
    if(dtPickerObj._compare($oElem.prop("tagName"), "INPUT"))
        $oElem.val(sElemValue);
    else
        $oElem.html(sElemValue);

    //ADDED THIS LINE
    $oElem.change();

        return sElemValue;
},
```

The plugin doesn't seem to have any eventing built-in, so doesn't look like there is a good way to react to the value being set otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That one line fixed it ;)

Comment: FYI, I submitted the change in their GitHub project and it's now in the latest release.

Comment: @TrueEddie - ah- nice to hear!